# создать .resx в проекте

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

В моем проекте блазор сервер, я добавила перевод, и для этого использую файлы с расширением .resx

Когда я добавляла перевод, я добавила этот файл вручную, то есть я создала какой-то .xaml файл, и исправила в ручную его расширение. и потом копировала старый пример и создавала для новых страниц, меняя имя файла.

У меня вопрос как его создать через список, чтоб сразу был с нужным .resx ? Что в списке надо искать ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашла ответ [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48637023/how-to-create-resx-files)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в поиске вбить res => выдает файл ресурсов, у него именно такое расширение✅ .resx